# eInk screen is causing reboot on RaspberryPi0W

Tags: raspberry-pi, crash, spi, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to get to work a raspberry pi 0 W and a pervasive display eink screen together.

But, every time when the screen refresh, it reboots the pi 0. Software works great on a RPi3 but not on Rpi0w with Raspbian Lite.

Here is the soft : [EpaperDisplay](https://github.com/f-necas/EpaperDisplay)

Here is the screen : [Screen](http://www.pervasivedisplays.com/products/740)

There is no log in `/var/log/messages`, neither in `/var/log/syslog`. Every time it reboots, it's erasing history, logs ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was a software issue, you would probably see something in the logs (or you'd at least see a kernel panic message on the console in the HDMI output if you have a screen connected there).

If you have nothing in the HDMI screen when the pi crashes, I'd suspect that the display is using more power than your power supply can provide. Try with a PSU with a higher ampere rating.

If a better power supply does not help, it can be that the display sucks too much 3.3v from the raspberry pi than the zero can provide. In that case you should try feeding the display via a separate 3.3v regulator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was the 5V output who was draining too much. I've used the micro usb output to supply the VIN input of the screen !